# How to create a manual view in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

The below view is not created. What is the issue?

### Method:

```
      def daily_flash_report_tree(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
          sql = """
            CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW report_view AS (
              SELECT 
                   id,name,job
                from   
                   sales_summary limit 10
             ) 

        """

        cr.execute(sql)

        return {
            'name': "Daily Flash Report",
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'daliy.flash.report',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'context': {"search_default_group_period": 1},
        }
```

### Object:

```
class daily_flah_report_new(osv.osv):

    _name = "daliy.flash.report"
    _auto = False

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name'),
        'job': fields.char('Job'),
    }
```

### View:

```
<record id="drill_flash_report_flash" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Report</field>
    <field name="model">daliy.flash.report</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <tree>
            <field name="name"   />
            <field name="job"   />
         </tree>
     </field>
</record>

<record id="drill_flash_report_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Net Revenue</field>
        <field name="res_model">daliy.flash.report</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_group_period": 1}</field>
</record>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the problem here? What does not work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please notice that you created view named "report_view"

> ```
>        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW report_view AS (
>           SELECT 
>                id,name,job
>             from   
>                sales_summary limit 10
>          )
> ```

Because your object is `daliy.flash.report` so your default table of your object is `daliy_flash_report`

> ```
> _name = "daliy.flash.report"
> _auto = False
> ```

They are different, you should make sure name of table of object is same as name of the view.
Solution: choose 1 or 2.

1. You should create view named `daliy_flash_report` by below comment

> ```
>    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW daliy_flash_report AS (
>       SELECT 
>            id,name,job
>         from   
>            sales_summary limit 10
>      )
> ```

2. Use attribute `_table` in your object to indicate table name.

> ```
>     class daily_flah_report_new(osv.osv):
>        _name = "daliy.flash.report"
>        _auto = False
>        _table = "report_view"
> ```

Good luck

Comment: Working great... Thanks@Hoang